# How is it possible to test a wear app is packaged correctly before publishing it to the play store?

Tags: android, wear-os

The documentation for packaging wearable apps states:

> "... *If* packaged properly, when users download the handheld app, the
>   system automatically pushes the wearable app to the paired wearable".

My question is how is it possible to test if the app is actually packaged properly? So that it will install correctly when its parent app is downloaded.

I thought I would be able to test it by:
- resetting the wearable device
- rooting the handheld device and placing the handheld apk in /system/app
- pair the device with the handheld and check the wearable app runs afterwards and thus it must have been installed.

However this didn't work as a test as the handheld app didn't run when placed in /system/app (I got a stopped running error, however the handheld app runs ok when installed normally via adb install).

So how is it possible to test the mobile app has been correctly packaged with the handheld app and will install before releasing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if under the raw package of your app was placed the apk of the wear app. You can open the apk with a simple zip. In addition you have to export your app signing with your key, install it on your smartphone. If the wear app is automatically installed on your smartwatch (or emulator) then the packaging is ok. No root or other operations are needed.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by this: "In addition you have to export your app signing with your key, install it on your smartphone."

Comment: Simply generate your app and sign it with developer key, put the apk on your phone and install it, really simple.

Comment: I thought you meant something else because "export your app signing with your key" implies there are two things, whereas it was just a typo and it should have been "export your app signed with your key"